# Image rendering with decimal pixels and css transition

Tags: html, css

If an image in an element with a decimal width is animated using css (opacity), the image loads at a fixed pixel width then after completing the transition changes size to the correct decimal pixels.

I have tested this on Chrome only. See the fiddle, which shows the problem only when using css animations. http://jsfiddle.net/minlare/kext0af4/

```
.opacity{
    width: 400px;
}
.opacity div {
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    float: left;
}
.opacity img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .25s;
}
.opacity img.visible{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Any way around this?

Comment: unrelated to question: Instead of `calc(100% / 3)`, you should be able to do `33.3333%` and have the same effect while supporting older browsers that lack the calc() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved adding `outline: 1px transparent solid;`

```
.opacity img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .25s;
    outline: 1px transparent solid;
}
```

Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/0dvvd1n1/

Also `backface-visibility: hidden;` [solves the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/pqmeeueg/) but the outline approach doesn't create sharpened edges.

Comment: Thanks! I went for outline in the end, seems like the most elegant solution, and also the image rendering seems cleaner compared to backface-visibility

Answer (score 1):

Another method to sort of solve it is to add `translate:transformZ(0)`  This forces GPU rendering, which corrects the jumping in the version I tested it in (Chrome 43.0.2357.132 on Mac).  However, it can cause issues if there are a large number of GPU rendered elements that have transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/kudj7zxn/

```
.opacity img{
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: .25s;
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```